# Custom Sub Magento Theme Not Working

Tags: magento, themes, magento-1.7

Hi my theme just updated to a new file organization that uses sub custom themes so that I can update the theme without overwriting the files I changed myself.

I downloaded the new theme and set up the new file path, but the site still reads from

**skin/frontend/default/shopper/css/styles.css**

when it should read from

**skin/frontend/shopper/default/css/styles.css**

I set the current package name to “shopper” and set default (under Design/Themes) to custom. I know I want my custom files of the theme to go under **shopper/custom**, and then magento should check for files at **shopper/default** and finally check for files at **base**. For some reason its ignoring the shopper directory and still referencing from the old default directory. 
And saved everything. I also disabled and flushed all the caches.

The two images attached show how I have it set up in magento via the admin and the ftp. I haven't been able to solve this for months.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

FIXED IT!

The issue was not in **System > Configuration > Design** but in fact **System > Design** I discovered that **System > Design** had it set up for Default/Shopper and there wasn't a time frame for it. The following link helped me reach my conclusion.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/197908/

You are supposed to **System > Design** for temporary theme changes, but my site had it set with no time frame thus always overwriting my settings in **System > Configuration > Design**